# Linking APR (Apache Portable Runtime) with CMake in Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, lnk2019, apr

i would like to compile a project using the apache portable runtime libraries (APR) and cmake.  It all looks good when running along with linux (as there i can use the apr-1-config shell script). Nevertheless, in windows it looks like `cmake` does not bind or link the included files correctly. I've tried some different methods, like importing the `libapr-1.lib` as static library or just `target_link_library` all stuff, yet nothing seems to work. I always get the

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
```

linker errors when compiling using visual studio. It does not matter which function i am calling, as an example i am calling `apt_pool_create`, as it does not require any parameters. 
I am still wondering as visual studio is finding the files with IntelliSense and showing me all documentations inline. Also the compiler does not fail to build when an `apt_pool*` pointer object is defined and initialized with NULL.

Maybe anyone does know why there are these linker problems. Following are some snippets out of the `CMakeLists.txt` files:

**CMakeLists.txt (partial)**

```
# Include unimrcp requirements (apr package)  
IF(WIN32) # Search APR in windows  
  INCLUDE(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/FindAPR_windows.cmake)  
ELSE(WIN32) # Search APR in unix  
  INCLUDE(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/FindAPR_unix.cmake)  
ENDIF(WIN32)  

# Set link libraries
SET(TARGET_LINK_LIBS
    ${APR_LIBRARIES}
    ${APRUTIL_LIBRARIES}
    ${PTHREADS}
)

SET(CLIENT_SOURCES ...)
SET(CLIENT_HEADERS ...)

# Include intermediary files
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} 
    ${APR_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${APRUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

# Add executable and link libraries
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${CLIENT_TARGET} src/main.cpp ${CLIENT_SOURCES} ${CLIENT_HEADERS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CLIENT_TARGET} ${TARGET_LINK_LIBS})
```

The `CLIENT_TARGET` is just a predefined target name for output.

[For windows i am using following FindAPR.cmake module (the FindAPR_windows.cmake file)](
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/celix/trunk/cmake/modules/FindAPR.cmake).

[For linux i am using following FindAPR.cmake module (the FindAPR_unix.cmake file)](https://github.com/FreeSWITCH/FreeSWITCH/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindAPR.cmake).

It searches for `apr-1-config` and executes the shell script.

In linux my APR_LIBRARIES variable looks like this:

```
-L/usr/lib;-lapr-1
```

Windows is directly using the library with its path:

```
{path_to_lib}/libapr-1.lib
```

CMake does not announce any errors for linking, as mentioned above Visual Studio does give me the LNK2019 errors when calling for any apr function.

Maybe someone does have a hint for this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that the full path to the libapr-1.lib file appears in the Property Pages of your `${CLIENT_TARGET}` exe in VS under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, and that this path is definitely correct?

Comment: I can confirm that the dependencies list the libapr-1.lib file with the correct path. That's why i'm struggling... It should find the path and link it, also the full lib path is added as general linker library path to the executable.